# I want to stack circular divs on top of each other

Tags: css, html

I have a circular div with a some css that makes it expand on mousover. I have no idea on how to start about making another bigger circle sit behind it with the same center point. This could create a ring around the first circle.

e.g.

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_HoDij8Z2tHY/TJzb854jDVI/AAAAAAAAEv4/dMzvpjkq8XI/s1600/concentric_circles1.jpg

an image example

I don't think i explained it very well! :/ Sorry! I need separate divs, not one that makes a outer ring!

Thanks in advance!

Here is my current code:

```
#circles
{
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
width:800px;
height:800px;
alignment-adjust:central;
}

.circle1
{position:relative;

margin-top:50%;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius:50%;
background: #ff3019; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%, #cf0404 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff3019), color-stop(100%,#cf0404)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* W3C */  

transition:1s;
-moz-transition: 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: 1s; /* Opera */
-ms-transition: 1s; /* IE9 (maybe) */

}

.circle1:hover
{
    top:-200px;
width:500px;
height:500px;

}
```

Comment: Have you written any code?

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle
{
    background-color: #aaf;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
}

.circle:hover:after
{
    content: "";
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    border: 1px solid #aaf;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -10px;
}
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/6XF57/1/

Note: might not work on [older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3aafter)

Comment: I need separate divs! E.g. a another circle div behind it, but bigger

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `background-clip` do to this.

**CSS**

```
div {
    height: 200px; width: 200px;
    border-radius: 120px;
    background-color: #40B3F7;
    -webkit-background-clip: content-box;
    -moz-background-clip: content-box;
    background-clip: content-box;
    padding: 20px;
    font: normal 30px/200px sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid transparent
}
div:hover {
    border: 1px solid #40B3F7;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>Lorem</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/kt6b8/1/)